# Using glade treeviewer to display data using c

Tags: c, gtk3

I'm trying to use glade GTK3 to display data with c programming.. I can't find simple example where i can use already created treeviewer on a glade project to show data from a file. I'm new in using this tool thank you.

Comment: Maybe [Chapter 1. Lists and Trees: the GtkTreeView Widget](http://scentric.net/tutorial/ch-treeview.html)?

Comment: If you assume to get a solution that automatically puts content from some file into a TreeView, you might run out of luck. You need to populate the storage for the TreeView on your own.

Comment: I resolved my problem. Thank you for your help.